# Correct arrow for mathematical limits

Tags: equations, arrows

I am currently using `$$\phi(\varepsilon) \overrightarrow{ \varepsilon \rightarrow 0 }0 $$` for writing down mathematical limits. But I am not very confident with this notation, as the text under the arrow is far too huge displayed. Does anybody here have a better suggestion

Comment: For limits, it is advised to use `\to` ... in math mode of course. A little hint: Do not use `$$...$$` but `\[...\]` instead.

Comment: ah, thank you. and how do you write some text under this arrow?

Comment: `\xrightarrow[under]{over}`

Comment: @user180097 However I would define something like `\tendsto{x\to\infty}` (more “logical”) to be something like `\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}`.

Comment: @Manuel this may be true, but just in case...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Why is `\[...\]` preferred over `$$...$$`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have two versions, depending on what you perhaps need.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\[ \phi(\varepsilon) \xrightarrow[\varepsilon \to 0]{} 0 \]

\[ \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \phi(\varepsilon) = 0 \]
\end{document}
```

I prefer the `\lim` style, it is mathematical cleaner, but that is also a matter of taste.

[image]

Comment: [Why should the minimal class be avoided](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided)

Comment: @Manuel: I used an old template, but I know about the caveats of `minimal` ;-)

Comment: I insist that the formula is:

`\xrightarrow[ THE LIMIT ]{}`.